# Camel Kafka S3 Source Connector with multiple connectors for same bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-camel-aws, s3-kafka-connector

I am trying to define Camel S3 Source connectors. I have searched quite a bit without success to find answers to below questions.

- How can I set up my connector  such that the file in the S3 bucket doesn't get deleted but can  be moved to another folder specified by me, after it  is processed
- Is it possible  to define separate connectors with different value converters for the same bucket, maybe by folders  under the bucket?  The connectors will use different kafka topics based on the file type.  How can I define the bucket with folder when defining the connector properties

Thank you

Comment: Buckets don't have folders. They're called prefixes. Surely there is a prefix config for where to source from within the bucket

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  It is a bit confusing, because when you access S3 from console, it says "Create Folder".  Looking for prefix helped find the config keys.